# Meteor user.manual variable increment error

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am having a problem with one of my functions in Meteor.methods.

Currently, it is:

```
click: function () {
Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId}, {$inc: {'money': 25 }});
}
```

But, I want to make money increase by a variable variable stored in the user called manual. Like this:

```
click: function () {
Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId}, {$inc: {'money': user.manual }});
}
```

But, when I try to do this, I receive this error:

```
I20140131-16:33:40.876(-5)? Exception while invoking method 'click' ReferenceError: user is not defined
I20140131-16:33:40.876(-5)?     at Meteor.methods.click (app/server/server.js:29:62)
I20140131-16:33:40.876(-5)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1346)
I20140131-16:33:40.876(-5)?     at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:539
I20140131-16:33:40.876(-5)?     at _.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:35)
I20140131-16:33:40.877(-5)?     at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:538
I20140131-16:33:40.877(-5)?     at _.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:35)
I20140131-16:33:40.877(-5)?     at _.extend.protocol_handlers.method (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:537)
I20140131-16:33:40.877(-5)?     at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:437
```

Here is my onCreateUser Method:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
user.money = 0;
user.rate = 1;
user.manual = 25;
return user;
})
```

I user user.rate successfully in another part of my program also in the server.js file:

```
  Meteor.startup(function () {
     Meteor.setInterval(function() {
       Meteor.users.find({}).map(function(user) {
          Meteor.users.update({_id: user._id}, {$inc: {'money': user.rate}})
     });
     }, 1000)
  });
```

When I change the user.rate to user.manual, money does increment by the user.manual value. So I'm so confused why user.manual won't work in Meteor.methods. Why does it say User is not defined?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what is wrong.

```
ReferenceError: user is not defined
```

You should be using `Meteor.user()`.

> Meteor.user()  Anywhere but publish functions
>
> Get the current user record, or null if no user is logged in. A
>   reactive data source.